# Causing an alert to go off if a command isn't done in certain time

Tags: c#, discord.net

My goal is to make a message send 10 minutes after a command isn't done, and then at 1 minute intervals after that. At first I tried something like this:

```
namespace MinecraftClient.ChatBots
{
    public class WallTimer
    {

        public static Timer wallTimer;

        internal static Task StartTimer()
        {
            wallTimer = new Timer()
            {
                Interval = 60000,
                AutoReset = true,
                Enabled = true
            };
            wallTimer.Elapsed += OnTimerTicked;

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private static void OnTimerTicked(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Program.SendAlertDiscord();
        }
    }
}
```

I was going to stop the timer when a command was sent, wait 10 minutes, then start the timer again. I had trouble defining using the `timer.Stop` function, as I believe it doesn't function with `System.Timers`. If anyone has a more efficient way of sending these alerts out 10 minutes later, I'm open to suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need not to stop timer for the requirement. Timer has one method `Change` than allows when task will again elapse, you can change it depending on your business as you need.
An example which you can modify can be

```
wallTimer= new Timer(new TimerCallback(OnTimerTicked));//OnTimerTicked is function for anything to do when timer is done

DateTime scheduledTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10);//Can be configurable 

TimeSpan timeSpan = scheduledTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);
int dueTime = Convert.ToInt32(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
wallTimer.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);
```

You can write recursive function calling itself every 10 minute or 1 min based on set configurable condition

Some example you can refer are :

http://www.nullskull.com/q/10075796/create-an-infinite-loop-in-a-windows-service.aspx
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=415982&seqNum=2

Comment: If the function that calls it goes off within the 10 minute time period, will the timer's cycle restart?

Comment: If the function is recursive if will poll indefinitely after configurable time till you stop windows service